# objects not saving in correct location

Tags: modeling, rendering

so when I open my project, certain objects are in the wrong (original) place.  I have moved the eyeballs and 3rd eye, parented them to the body, and saved about 5 times and every time I open it they are back in the original place.  Also when I correct the placement I try to render and it doesn't have eyeballs or 3rd eye in render.  How can I save the location? I tried to add a keyframe (even though Im just making one still frame) but blender quit immediately. thanks in advance any help is greatly appreciated!!  Here is a screenshot of how it looks when I open it, how I want it to look, and how its rendering...[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the location of your objects ? (with Ctrl+A -> Apply location)

Comment: sounds like there are keyframes on location...? if not, please provide your blend file

Comment: Got it working, thank you, I think I had a bunch of old parents in the mix.  I cleared them and can now move things